# Extra lines before embedded gwt application in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt

I noticed there is at least two line linebreak after top html code 
before embedded gwt application in case of IE6/7/8, For other browser, 
this cannot be seen.

E.g. html code

```
<body> 
mymenu 
<div id="gwtapplication"></div> 
</body>
```

There will be two lines after mymenu and gwt application. Note the 
application uses absolute panel which may be relevant. 
There is no problem if there is no mymenu like html code. A very 
simple text already produces this effect. 
Moving up the gwt application by repositioning the absolute y 
coordinate does not help because then the top of the application is 
hidden by the white horizontal wide "line". 

I have tried and failed:

```
-changed <div> for <span>
-changed margin and padding of body to zero.
-added display:block-inline style
```

Removing mymenu "fixes" it. Also, if gwt application is not embedded, div tag can be influenced.

Any ideas? T

Answer (score 0):

If it's a structural problem, you fix it by changing HTML elements accordingly. If it's a render problem, you should fix it using CSS.

It seems that you have a render problem for ie only. I suggest that you put 'mymenu' inside an element (eg: span) and control its appearance through css, either inline or using a style sheet.